# Cross dimensional segmented operation

Tags: python, numpy, jax

Say you have the following `a` array

```py
>>> a = np.arange(27).reshape((3,3,3))
>>> a
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]], dtype=int64)
```

And `m`, an array that specifies segment ids

```py
>>> m = np.linspace(start=0, stop=6, num=27).astype(int).reshape(a.shape)
>>> m
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[2, 2, 2],
        [2, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3]],

       [[4, 4, 4],
        [4, 5, 5],
        [5, 5, 6]]])
```

When using [JAX](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and wishing to perform, say, a sum over the scalars in `a` that share the same id in `m`, we can rely on [`jax.ops.segment_sum`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.ops.segment_sum.html).

```
>>> jax.ops.segment_sum(data=a.ravel(), segment_ids=m.ravel())
Array([10, 26, 42, 75, 78, 94, 26], dtype=int64)
```

Note that I had to resort to [`numpy.ndarray.ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ravel.html) since `~.segment_sum` assumes `m` to indicate the segments of data [*along its leading axis*](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.ops.segment_sum.html#:%7E:text=that%20indicates%20the%20segments%20of%20data%20(along%20its%20leading%20axis)).

---

**Q1** : Can you confirm there is no better approach, either with or without JAX ?

**Q2** : How would one then build `n`, an array that results from the replacement of the ids with the just-performed sums ? Note that I am not interested in non-vectorized approaches such as [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

```py
>>> n
array([[[10, 10, 10],
        [10, 10, 26],
        [26, 26, 26]],

       [[42, 42, 42],
        [42, 75, 75],
        [75, 75, 75]],

       [[78, 78, 78],
        [78, 94, 94],
        [94, 94, 26]]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: `a[m==1]`, selecting all elements of `a` for a specific `m` value, retursn a flat array.  That's the nature of `boolean` masking.  Or you could make a copy of `a`, and set all elements that don't match chosen `m` to some sort of 'fill', such as 0 or `np.nan`.  In either case  you could apply some function to the non-masked values, such as sum.  Otherwise, `numpy` doesn't provide much help in pairing vallues with multiple `ids`.  `numpy` is best for regular  'whole-array' operations,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `segment_sum` operation is somewhat more specialized than what you're asking about. In the case you describe, I would use [`ndarray.at`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.numpy.ndarray.at.html) directly:

```py
sums = jnp.zeros(m.max() + 1).at[m].add(a)
print(sums[m])
```

```
[[[10. 10. 10.]
  [10. 10. 26.]
  [26. 26. 26.]]

 [[42. 42. 42.]
  [42. 75. 75.]
  [75. 75. 75.]]

 [[78. 78. 78.]
  [78. 94. 94.]
  [94. 94. 26.]]]
```

This will also work when the segments are non-adjacent.

Comment: What do you mean by "more specialized", the adjacency requirement ?

Comment: I mean that it assumes your segments lie along the leading axis, which does not match your use case.

Answer (score 2):

Use `np.bincount` with `a` as the `weights` parameter:

```
s = np.bincount(m.ravel(), weights = a.ravel())
s
Out[]: array([10., 26., 42., 75., 78., 94., 26.])
```

And to put the values back in the array:

```
n = s[m]
n
Out[]: 
array([[[10., 10., 10.],
        [10., 10., 26.],
        [26., 26., 26.]],

       [[42., 42., 42.],
        [42., 75., 75.],
        [75., 75., 75.]],

       [[78., 78., 78.],
        [78., 94., 94.],
        [94., 94., 26.]]])
```

Comment: Thx for your answer +1, especially the second part. `np.bincount` hardly generalizes to non-sum operations.

Comment: A sum is what was requested.  Are the segments in `m` always contiguous?  If so you might be able to do a `ufunc.reduceat` operation (if your operation is a `ufunc`), but otherwise you're probably best served by a `numba` function.

Comment: Where is sum written in the title ? Operation. And saying "wishing to perform, say, a sum" is clearly not to be understood as "I want a sum". JAX and Numba do not interact very well.